# Python: Calculate month, Quarter details from number of quarters

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to calculate month, Quarter details from number of quarters

Example: Current date = 29-April-2017

I/p:

```
No_of_quarters=6
```

O/p:

```
Quarters = ["Q1-2016","Q2-2016", "Q3-2016", "Q4-2016", "Q1-2017", "Q2-2017"]
Months = ["Jan-2016","Feb-2016","Mar-2016","Apr-2016","May-2016","Jun-2016","Jul-2016","Aug-2016","Sep-2016","Oct-2016","Nov-2016","Dec-2016","Jan-2017","Feb-2017","Mar-2017","Apr-2017"]
```

Is there any predefined functions i can re-use ? or i need to calculate using following way

```
today = datetime.date.today()
month = int(today.strftime("%m")) - 1 
quarter = month / 3 + 1
quarter_Name = "Q" + str(quarter)  + "-" +  today.strftime("%Y")
month_name = today.strftime("%b") + "-" +  today.strftime("%Y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas and the no_of_quarters input

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

No_of_quarters=6

today = datetime.date.today()
month = pd.Period(today, freq='M')
quarter = month.asfreq('Q-DEC')

print "Quarters:"
for x in range (0,No_of_quarters-1):
    print quarter-x

print "Months:"
for x in range (0,(No_of_quarters*3)-1):
    print month-x
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Try timeindex in pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#periodindex-and-period-range)

Examples:

```
import pandas as pd
prng = pd.period_range('01/01/2017', '04/29/2017', freq='Q')

print(prng)
PeriodIndex(['2017Q1', '2017Q2'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')

# Change freq to 'M'
prng = pd.period_range('01/01/2017', '04/29/2017', freq='M')

print(prng)
PeriodIndex(['2017-01', '2017-02', '2017-03', '2017-04'],
             dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```